# Nuxtjs and Docker: package file copied but only partially installed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I ran into a weird error.  I have a simple dockerized nuxt project:

```sh
mkdir my-project
cd my-project
npx create-nuxt-app frontend
```

This results in a project repo with structure:

```
my-project/
|-- frontend/
    |-- Dockerfile.development
    |-- assets/
    |-- ... (standard nuxt stuff)
|-- .env
|-- .dockerignore
docker-compose-development.yml
```

Below is the docker-compose.development.yml and Dockerfile.development files. I have a  dependency in my package `valph`a which I cat in the Dockerfile to make sure I am not going insane (and the output shows that the package file is correct). When I build, `npm run install` runs (without using cache). Yet when I spin up the service, I get an error that some dependencies installed is not there! 
I have tried:

- pruning old volumes
- building with `--no-cache` option
- deleting `.nuxt`, `node_modules` directories and rebuilding

various combinations of above

Thoughts?

## Logs

### `docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml build`

```
Building nuxt
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10.15
 ---> 5a401340b79f
Step 2/7 : ENV APP_ROOT /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f17aa506d708
Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c553d4194eb
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b35e54cee978
Step 5/7 : COPY ./frontend ${APP_ROOT}
 ---> 8e1c3daf89d7
Step 6/7 : RUN cat ${APP_ROOT}/package.json
{
  "dependencies: {
    ...,
    "valpha": "0.0.6"
  }
}
Step 7/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ...
```

### `docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up`

```
Attaching to nuxt_test
nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  | > frontend@1.0.0 dev /src
nuxt_1  | > nuxt
nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  | ℹ Listening on: http://172.23.0.2:3000/
nuxt_1  | ℹ Preparing project for development
nuxt_1  | ℹ Initial build may take a while
nuxt_1  | ✔ Builder initialized
nuxt_1  | ✔ Nuxt files generated
nuxt_1  | ℹ Compiling Client
nuxt_1  | ✔ Client: Compiled with some errors in 27.09s
nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  |  ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors
nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  | These dependencies were not found:
nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  | * valpha in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/Table.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/table.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 1 other

nuxt_1  | 
nuxt_1  | To install them, you can run: npm install --save valpha
nuxt_1  | ℹ Waiting for file changes
nuxt_1  | ℹ Memory usage: 429 MB (RSS: 590 MB)
```

## Files

### `/frontend/Dockerfile.development`

```
FROM node:10.15

ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

COPY ./frontend ${APP_ROOT}

RUN cat ${APP_ROOT}/package.json

RUN npm install
```

### `/docker-compose.development.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt_test:
    image: frontend_test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile.development
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run dev"
    environment:
      - HOST
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/src
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "d3": "^5.14.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.51.1",
    "valpha": "0.0.6",
    "vue-scrollactive": "^0.8.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is one spun out of laziness! Since there is no directory `node_modules` (as the OP states deleting it), when mounting:

```
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/src
```

the OP's lack of original `node_modules` overwrites the `node_modules` installed (as `npm install` installs `node_modules` under `/frontend` in this example)

To circumvent this, mount each nuxt related subdirectory individually:

```
- ./frontend/assets:/src/assets
- ./frontend/components:/src/components
- ./frontend/layouts:/src/layouts
- ./frontend/pages:/src/pages
- ./frontend/plugins:/src/plugins
- ./frontend/static:/src/static
- ./frontend/store:/src/store
```